# How to run IE from cmd adding custom letters to address predefined in shortcut

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer, shortcuts

Question may be little bit complicated but let me explain. First I wanted to open certain webpage using "run" dialog and a shortcut. I have managed that using windows link pointing to IE and looking like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://somewebpage
```

Lets say I have named this shortcut as "shortcut" and added the location to the PATH. Now when I open "run" (windows+R)  I can just type shortcut and the somewebpage.com would be opened in IE.

Now it is the tricky part. I want to add from the cmd certain letters to the end of url beeing opened. When typing in the run/cmd prompt:

```
shortcut something
```

I would expect that browser should open somewebpage/something, but instead of this it brings up *somewebpage/%20something*

Any ideas how to get rid of this unwanted space(%20) in the url?

Regards, Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Since passing a parameter to a shortcut will add a space no matter what, why don't you just create a batch script that can accept a parameter and open the page you want?

```
@echo off
::The %~1 will remove any quotes from the passed parameter. If there's none
::then it will open the default page.
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.superuser.com/%~1
```

Save it in your path with the name of your preference. Then click on `Start->Run` and type in `yourshortcutname` without a parameter. Superuser.com should open. Now, click on `Start->Run` again, and type in `yourshotcutname search` and the Search page for superuser.com should open.

Hope that helps.